# Why are dissertation-based books looked down upon?

Tags: publications, thesis, books

I came across the following [statement](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/infoServices/emsguide.html) by the Chicago University Press:

> If your book has its origins in a dissertation, your acknowledgments should not draw attention to this fact, as it will discourage library sales and book review attention.

Why are dissertation-based books looked down upon?

A dissertation-based book is not necessarily of low quality. I was surprised to read such a statement from a respected publisher. Isn't this unprofessional? If there is such a stereotype, shouldn't a publisher like the Chicago University Press refrain from nurturing it?

Comment: You might expect that if your book is based on a dissertation, and the dissertation is freely available through your library, then people might be inclined to download the dissertation rather than pay for the book.

Comment: Interesting perspective, but it does not account for the second consequence in the statement: "book review attention," which seems related to quality. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @EasternRiver Why not? Who wants to review a book no one will buy?

Comment: @BryanKrause I think books are also reviewed to contribute to scholarly discussion. I sometimes have a book before I go searching for reviews, to see what others think of it, especially if it is not critiqued elsewhere. Maybe you are right. I'm young and a novice.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know much about it either; in my field no one would ever consider publishing a dissertation as a book so its no issue. Another problem with dissertations as books, however, is that there are several disreputable publishers that go after recent dissertations and try to get their authors to agree to publish them as a book. There's really no benefit to the author, they charge extreme prices, and they basically just hope a few people are stupid enough to buy a couple copies of the books, while offering thousands of them. The costs to them are essentially zero.

Comment: If you're looking for a definitive explanation of the Chicago Press policy, perhaps you'd best ask someone at Chicago Press to explain it?

Comment: @BryanKrause I think your suggestion applies to publishing in general. Low quality books/dissertations will get attracted to low quality publishers. The authors benefit by adding the publication to their list. Some low-quality universities or employers (especially nationally or locally) may be impressed nonetheless. An author/student who believes in the quality of their work (someone considering Chicago Press for example) would not go to these publishers. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Tyler That's another suggestion, but I asked here because it does not seem restricted to this press (a general stereotype/pattern/way of thinking). Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's a policy, it seems like a strong suggestion to authors, and they give two reasons.

Comment: In my eyes and my field (chemistry): if the content of the PhD thesis is not published in peer reviewed journals within 2 years  it isn't worth reading in 95% of the cases. I wouldn't buy such a book. If it's published in peer reviewed articles then there's no point in buying the book anyways.

Comment: In my field (sociology), a student is expected to derive up to two or three journal articles from the dissertation, and normally this should not exhaust the dissertation's originality, meaning a good one should still be worth turning into a book or buying.

Comment: Odd.  When reviewing literature (and when assessing students' ability to review literature), I take the view that a PhD dissertation (at least, one which has led to the candidate passing the PhD) is in a class of source with _better_ quality assurance than a book, because the PhD examining process somewhat simulates peer review.  In any case, the point is moot, because the University of Chicago Press has now deleted the sentence you quoted from the web page you linked.

Answer (score 6):

Simply compare the number of dissertations and books published in a field. A dissertation can be strong enough to provide enough material for a technical book, but it is rarely the case. A dissertation is normally focused on a specific research work, but a book is expected to be comprehensive. In rare cases, a PhD student has a comprehensive perspective of the field to write a flawless book.

It is legitimate and understandable that a publisher (university-based or independent) pays a particular attention to the marketing factors. The readers normally expect a book written by an experienced academic rather than a PhD student.

The publisher simply avoids highlighting any point, which might have a negative impact on the potential buyers, and leave them to judge the book based on its contents. They simply want to **avoid prejudice about the book**.

So, don't worry, they do not undermine the quality of PhD dissertations.

And believe me, marketing is as technical as your field of study, and has its own rules.

Comment: "A dissertation is normally focused on a specific research work, but a book is expected to be comprehensive." Maybe that's true for technical fields. In my field (social science), a dissertation "on a specific research work" is book material.
As to "writ[ing] a flawless book," that can be gleaned from the publisher of the work. A book by Chicago Press means a "a flawless book," if there is such a thing, meaning it is worth the investment. 
"They simply want to avoid prejudice about the book." Chicago Press is, I believe, already in a position to fight prejudice not just avoid it. 
+1